# Data Formatting within a txt. File

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following txt file that needs to be formatted with specific start and end positions for data throughout the file. For instance, column 1 is blank and will be read as an entry number. The values for this data type is a numeric 9 and should have the following positions (1-9). Next is employee ID with positions (10-15).. and so on. Values do not need a delimiter.

```
,MB4858,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,MD6535,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,PM7858,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,RM0111,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,RY2585,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,TM0617 ,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,VE2495,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,VJ8913,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,FJ4815 ,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,OM0188,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225D,,,DF2016,CA4310,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H00858,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H08392,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H15624,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H27573,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H40249,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H44581,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H48473,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H51570,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H55768,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H64315,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H71507,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H72248,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H78527,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H90393,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
,H95973,01,1,CA,07/18/20,0,0,4.8,,,,,,14.77,,Y,2225DH,,,DF2016,CA4311,,0172CA,,,,,Y,
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Python output formatting and string manipulation are documented in many places on line.  Where is the code that's giving you problems?

Comment: Are you sure? This looks more like a csv file.

Comment: Yes, it is a csv file that I exported from excel. I want to edit the format, remove the comma delimiter and add a specific value(spaces) between each data type.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting here:

```
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]

outFile = "newFile.txt"

with open(inFile, 'r') as inf, open(outFile, 'w') as outf:

        for line in inf:
            line = line.split(',')
            print(line)
```

Where sys argv[1] is the name of your txt file when you run the python script from the command line.

You can see that it will print out a list containing individual strings between the comma delimiters you have in your txt data file. From there you can do list manipulations to format the data. And then write it to outf like so (example):

```
# do what ever manipulations here to the output line 

output_line = line[0] + " " + line[1]
                outf.write(output_line)
                outf.write('\n'
```